# 0x OrderBook API is not storing the orders

Tags: 0x

I want to send out 2 signed orders. I am pulling the orderBook to check for the orders and have them accessible for use. This is the way I am doing the order and signing it. The issue is that I have been doing it since July and for some reason on August 16th the orders stopped showing up on this endpoint. All kinds of help will be much appreciated

````
  const ETHvToDAIOrder = await new protocolUtils.LimitOrder({
    makerToken: _takerTokenAddress,
    takerToken: _makerTokenAddress,
    makerAmount: ETHvToDAIMakerAmountBN,
    takerAmount: ETHvToDAITakerAmountBN,
    maker: botConfig.makerAddress,
    taker: NULL_ADDRESS,
    expiry: expiryTimeBN.toString(),
    salt: saltBN.toString(),
    chainId: botConfig.CHAIN_ID,
  });

  // sign the ETHvToDAI order
  signature = await ETHvToDAIOrder.getSignatureWithKey(privateKey);
  const signedETHvToDAIOrder = { ...ETHvToDAIOrder, signature };```
````

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to reproduce your issue. Could you please share more details about your API call?

Your issue is with the `/sra/v4/orderbook` endpoint, correct? Do you API calls return any error messages?

Comment: Hello Megan, thanks for the response! Yes, you are right my problem is with `/sra/v4/orderbook`. I know that orders are going through because I can see them in the `/sra/v4/orders` endpoint. API calls pass without any errors. I can not figure out what happend to the `orderbook` endpoint since it just stopped working for me.

Comment: This is the snippet of the POST order
```const responseDE = await fetch("https://api.0x.org/sra/v4/orders", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(signedOrders),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });```

Comment: `signedOrders` is an array consisting of 2 signed `LimitOrders`

Comment: The `/sra/v4/orderbook` endpoint is working for me. Please try pasting this code into your terminal:  `curl "https://api.0x.org/sra/v4/orderbook?quoteToken=0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2&baseToken=0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f"`